# Create an excel sheet from a loopback api's response

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

Is there any ways to create an excel sheet from the response of a loopback API?

Here is the sample response body

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "testSuite": {
    "name": "testsuite2",
    "id": 8,
    "userId": 3
  },
  "testCase": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "testCaseId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "testCaseId": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sure, it would help if you posted a sample output of the returned values by the api!

Comment: @NumantSantz I updated it. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would clean up the response object and create a variable with the data I want to write to the excel sheet in a simple structure as the `obj` variable in my example below. The fastest approach is to use `json2xls`. The code below can be used as part of your api endpoint which will result in writing an xlsx file in the root folder of your project

```
    var obj = [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "testCaseId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "testCaseId": 4
      }
    ];

    var fs = require('fs');
    var json2xls = require('json2xls');
    var xls = json2xls(obj);
    fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```